# Defining multiple whitelisted IP ranges for multiple rules on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using a cloud service that may send requests from an IP that falls under one of 9 IP ranges. I need to setup security groups on AWS so requests from any of these IP ranges are valid. The obvious solution is that I can use multiple rules and use one of the IP ranges for each rule. However, that is inefficient. To add to this, I will need to open up multiple rules with the same 9 IP ranges, which makes it repetitive and more costly. For example, if I want to setup 10 different rules, I'll have to set each one up 9 times and manage 10 * 9 = 90 rules.

I've looked at [AWS documentation on Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules) and looks like the only thing I could potentially use is to use another security group but I am not sure if that can help me either. I also found [this older post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=191133) from the AWS forum and I'm hoping there is a better answer.
Does anyone have a simpler solution?

Comment: If you trust the source ips then just open all traffic to them. Certainly simple if that is your  objective. Then use a local firewall to limit access to your service ports.

Answer (score 2):

If your 9 IPs can't be represented by a single rule, you would have to put then in individual rules. However, once a security group with such rules is created it can be reused for multiple purpose. What exactly is inefficient here?